# How to replace null field values with an empty string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I need to replace the null values in the Estimate Number field with a blank string. I have tried the code below and the values still appear as null. Any thoughts? thanks

```
Pro Number      Estimate Number

10271943        NULL
10271944        NULL
10271945        NULL
10271946        NULL
10271948        94606


SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
    (SELECT TOP 1 isnull(a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE,'') 
    FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
    WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND 
    a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 4 
    ORDER BY a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
    ) AS "Estimate Number"

FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE

WHERE a.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 AND d.AAADATETYPE = 1  
GROUP BY a.AAAREFNUMVALUE,a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE,a.AAAREFNUMTYPE;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when the subquery returns no values.  The `isnull()` needs to go *outside* the subquery:

```
ISNULL( (SELECT TOP 1 a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
         FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
         WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND 
               a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 4 
         ORDER BY a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
        ), ''
      ) AS "Estimate Number"
```

Note that this is a situation where `ISNULL()` is preferred over `COALESCE()`, because the SQL Server implementation of `COALESCE()` evaluates the first argument twice when it is not `NULL`.

However, you might find the query easier to express and faster to run if you use window functions instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
       COALESCE(a.AAAREFNUMVALUE_4, '') as "Estimate Number"
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             MAX(CASE WHEN a.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 4 THEN a.AAAREFNUMVALUE END) OVER (PARTITION BY a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE) as AAAREFNUMVALUE_4
      FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a
     ) a INNER JOIN
     dbo.AAATODATES d
     ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
WHERE a.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 AND d.AAADATETYPE = 1  ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. You're always quick to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try case, just make the adjusts:

```
CASE 
(SELECT TOP 1 a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
    FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
    WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND 
    a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 4 
    ORDER BY a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE) as Estimate Number
  WHEN NULL THEN ''
  ELSE 
    a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
END as "Estimate Number"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 isnull(a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE,'') 
    FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
    WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND 
    a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 4 
    ORDER BY a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE
    ),'') AS "Estimate Number"

FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE

WHERE a.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 AND d.AAADATETYPE = 1  
GROUP BY a.AAAREFNUMVALUE,a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE,a.AAAREFNUMTYPE;
```